# Car rental using promo code found on internet

Tags: car-rentals

Is it safe to rent a car in USA and use one of the promo codes you can find on internet (for example AWD (Avis Worldwide Discount) number)?

Can car rental company ask me where I found a code, or if I have their customer card with this number, or loyalty program, etc?

Comment: Generally, T&Cs for any car rental company state that you must be in possession of the valid card giving you the discount when you pick up the vehicle.  In practice however I've never ever been asked to show it.

Comment: They certainly can ask you for the card / program / voucher to go with a given promotion code, whether they will is likely to vary on both the level of discount and the location